# How can we modify nested object values without modifying original object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How can I change all nested object values to "true" without using extra space Can anyone help me in this.
I have tried in this way but I am not getting the logic to handle the nested object

P.S: Please don't concentrate about "true" or "false" is in string because it is mock data,I just want logic to implement which I am failing to do.

```js
const config = {
  header:{"logo":"true","nav":"false","user":"false"},
  searchResults:{"listView":"false","favorite":"true","share":"false","pagination":"true","filters":"true","sortBy":"false"},
  sharedLinks:{},
  learnerLinks:{},
  lukePreview:{"toc":"false","controls":"false"},
  lukeLaunch:{"toc":"false","controls":"false"},
  misc:{"import":"true"}
}

function changeBoolean(obj,propName){
  for(let i in obj){
    if( typeof obj[i] === 'object'){
       changeBoolean(obj[i],i)
    }
  }
  return obj
}
console.log(changeBoolean(config,'header'))
```

Comment: _"without modifying the original object"_ - What do you mean here exactly? The _"nested object values"_ are part of that original object. Do you want a copy of the `config` and only modify that copy?

Comment: You changed _"without modifying the original object"_ to _"without using extra space"_ what does that mean?

Comment: @Andreas It means my updated object should be same object which I have created but not a new object or I don't want to create a new object for solving and I am newbie  suggest if I am wrong

Comment: Your code is not changing anything to the given object. There is no property assignment in your function. Secondly, there are no boolean values in your data.

Comment: Why are you using strings (`"true"` and `"false"`) instead of booleans (`true`/`false`)?

Answer (score 2):

Try to assign the function's result, like this:

```
function changeBoolean(obj, propName) {
  for (let i in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[i] === "object") {
      obj[i] = changeBoolean(obj[i], propName);
    } else {
      obj[i] = "true";
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: can you give some explanation why we are storing recursive function value in obj[i]

Comment: Function `changeBoolean` return `obj`, so if we need to change obj nested value, then we must change obj[i] value with the correct value.

Comment: obj[i] = changeBoolean(obj[i], propName); Here from function we are returning an object  and stored in obj[i] and obj[i] is Object now and how that object is iterated I am not able to get it. Can you explain me better or provide some releavent example to understand your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const config = {
  header: { "logo": "true", "nav": "false", "user": "false" },
  searchResults: { "listView": "false", "favorite": "true", "share": "false", "pagination": "true", "filters": "true", "sortBy": "false" },
  sharedLinks: {},
  learnerLinks: {},
  lukePreview: { "toc": "false", "controls": "false" },
  lukeLaunch: { "toc": "false", "controls": "false" },
  misc: { "import": "true" }
}

const changeBoolean = o => Object.entries(o).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  a[k] = typeof v === 'object' ? changeBoolean(v)  : 'true'
  return a
}, {})
const newConfig = changeBoolean(config)

console.log(newConfig)
```

Comment: This code will not convert all false values to true and I asked how can we convert all nested object's "false" => "true" .

Comment: I did because of param `propName` but yes.. I am agree with you

Comment: Updated answer. Thank you

Comment: ` a[k] = typeof v === 'object' 
    ? changeBoolean(v, propName) ` Can you explain what propName is going on every iteration.

Comment: Added code refactor to remove parameter unused `propName`

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> Can we modify nested object values without modifying original object?

This sounds like a contradiction. When you mutate a nested object, then that is a mutation of the original object. It looks like you want immutability. This means that as soon as you need a change in a nested object, you create a copy of it that has the change, and this change will then bubble upwards, resulting in new copies of objects as they receive a new "child" object.

> ...without extra space

You cannot have both: either you mutate the original object (in its nested parts), or you create a new one. If you don't want the original object to mutate, then you obviously need space for the replacing object.

#### Some issues

- Your input object has no boolean values. It has strings like "false" and "true", but those are not booleans. So I suggest to work with truly boolean values, without the quotes
- Your code is not setting any property, so it can never mutate anything to your object
- Your data has no "header" property, so that would be another reason why your code could not have changed anything.
- The second argument you pass to the recursive call is `i`, which is not the property you wanted to change. You should just pass `propName` there.

#### Some assumptions I'll make

- The function is to return the original object when it finds that there is nothing change. This should also be the principle for nested objects.
- When the object has a property with the given name, but it is not a boolean, then it will not be changed. Only when that property value is a boolean there will be a change
- The change will *toggle* the boolean. So if it was `false` it should become `true` and vice versa.
- No object should be *mutated*. If something changes, a new object should be created and returned.

Here is how I would do that. This snippet runs with 2 test cases: one that doesn't change anything, and another that does:

```js
function changeBoolean(obj, propName) {
  if (Object(obj) !== obj) return obj; // A primitive value: nothing changes
  let changed = false;
  let pairs = Object.entries(obj).map(function ([key, value]) {
    let changedValue = key === propName && typeof value === "boolean" ? !value
                     : changeBoolean(value, propName);
    changed ||= changedValue !== value;
    return [key, changedValue];
  });
  return changed ? Object.fromEntries(pairs) : obj;
}

const config = {
  header:{logo: true, nav: false, user: false},
  searchResults:{listView: false, favorite: true, share: false, pagination: true, filters: true, sortBy: false},
  sharedLinks:{},
  learnerLinks:{},
  lukePreview:{toc: false, controls: false},
  lukeLaunch:{toc: false, controls: false},
  misc:{import: true}
};

// Test 1
let header = changeBoolean(config, 'header');
console.log("header:", header === config ? "no change" : header);

// Test 2
let toc = changeBoolean(config, 'toc');
console.log("toc:", toc === config ? "no change" : toc);
```